# Rstudio error message lm

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear, lm

When I try to a linear regression model of my data and put in lm(DrinkDeath_1_1_~A1+A2+A3) I keep getting this: Error in model.frame.default(formula = DrinkDeath_1_1_ ~ A1, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'DrinkDeath_1_1_' as an error message.

My linear model should be in this shape B = A1 * X1 + A2 * X2 + A3 * X3 and the names of the dataset are "Index" "A0"    "A1"    "A2"    "A3"    "A4"    "B".

How can I make this linear regression?

Comment: The error is telling you that `DrinkDeath_1_1` is not of the right type.  It should be a single  numeric vector. Try `str(DrinkDeath_1_1)` Perhaps `DrinkDeath_1_1 = as.numeric(DrinkDeath_1_1)` will help.